# ImportError: No module named sympy

Tags: import, sympy

I am getting the following error while trying to run a sympy file in order to contribute to sympy. It is :

```
  ImportError: No module named sympy
```

I installed the sympy module through pip for both python2.7 and python 3.
Also, isympy is working. 
Strangly, when I try to import sympy in python's interactive console in the main sympy directory, no import errors are shown but in some other directory, it shows import errors.

Please help me to download the sympy module in a way that I will be able to run the code.

Thanks.

[Importing module in python console of main directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0R6o.png)

[Importing module in some other directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ7Pf.png)

Comment: It works when you are in the SymPy directory because Python imports modules from the current directory if they exist there.

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause here is that you are using two different Pythons. If you have Python installed multiple times (like Python 2 and Python 3), each has its own separate packages. You can check what Python you are using by printing `sys.executable`.

I should point out that for the purposes of contributing to SymPy, you generally want to run against the development version. That is, running Python from the SymPy directory and importing the development version from there, without actually installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
But I solved the problem. I realised that I didn't install sympy in the current conda environment. When I tried it using the command:

```
  conda install sympy
```

It worked and no error is being shown.

Thanks.